# Euro sign in table with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx, eurosym

I'm trying to align some money in a table using the S column type of the `siunitx` package, but the € symbol keeps running wild (inconsistent alignment).

Using the `eurosym` package helps with the alignment but puts the currency symbol up front and I would like to have it behind the number. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|S|S|S|S|}  

    \hline
    {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\ 
    \hline
    -199,37 € & 0,00 € & 33,27 € & 166,10 € \\
    252,56 € & 0,00 € & -409,58 € & 157,02 € \\
    104,67 € & 0,00 € & -40,18 € & -64,48 € \\
    0,17 € & 0,00 € & -2,52 € & 2,35 € \\
    0,00 € & 0,00 € & 0,00 € & 0,00 € \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|S|S|S|S|}  

    \hline
    {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\ 
    \hline
    \euro{-199,37} & \euro{0,00} & \euro{33,27} & \euro{166,10} \\
    \euro{252,56} & \euro{0,00} & \euro{-409,58} & \euro{157,02} \\
    \euro{104,67} & \euro{0,00} & \euro{-40,18} & \euro{-64,48} \\
    \euro{0,17} & \euro{0,00} & \euro{-2,52} & \euro{2,35} \\
    \euro{0,00} & \euro{0,00} & \euro{0,00} & \euro{0,00} \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Typographically, this is wrong and looks horrible. Remove all euro signs and add a table note stating: "_NOTE: All numbers in Euro_". Or move the euro sign to the column header: "_A (€) B (€)_" if you have columns that is not in Euro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\sisetup{table-space-text-post={\,€}, 
         table-align-text-post=false}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=-3.2]<{\,€}
                    S[table-format= 1.2]<{\,€} 
               *{2}{S[table-format=-3.2]<{\,€}}
                    }
    \toprule
\mc{A}  & \mc{B} & \mc{C} & \mc{D}  \cr
    \midrule
-199,37 & 0,00  &   33,27  & 166,10 \cr
 252,56 & 0,00  & -409,58  & 157,02 \cr
 104,67 & 0,00  &  -40,18  & -64,48 \cr
   0,17 & 0,00  &   -2,52  &   2,35 \cr
   0,00 & 0,00  &    0,00  &   0,00 \cr
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I would like to suggest an alternative solution: put the euro sign in the column headers.

And egreg suggests to use `eurosym` without the `gen` option, this way the euro symbol is more beautiful.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{SSSS}  
    \toprule    
    {A (\euro)} & {B (\euro)} & {C (\euro)} & {D (\euro)} \\ 
    \midrule
    -199,37  & 0,00  & 33,27  & 166,10  \\
    252,56  & 0,00  & -409,58  & 157,02  \\
    104,67  & 0,00  & -40,18  & -64,48  \\
    0,17  & 0,00  & -2,52  & 2,35  \\
    0,00  & 0,00  & 0,00  & 0,00  \\
    \bottomrule    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Or:
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{SSSS}  
    \toprule    
    {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\ 
    {(\euro)} & {(\euro)} & {(\euro)} & {(\euro)} \\ 
    \midrule
    -199,37  & 0,00  & 33,27  & 166,10  \\
    252,56  & 0,00  & -409,58  & 157,02  \\
    104,67  & 0,00  & -40,18  & -64,48  \\
    0,17  & 0,00  & -2,52  & 2,35  \\
    0,00  & 0,00  & 0,00  & 0,00  \\
    \bottomrule    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not using the horrible Euro symbol provided with the `gen` option to `eurosym` would be *a good thing*.

Comment: @egreg I copied from the OP's MWE. What should I use?

Comment: Just remove the `gen` option.

Comment: @egreg Done, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With the appropriate `table-format` option for the individual cells as well as with `table-space-text-post=€` and `table-align-text-post=true` you can get the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[h]
\sisetup{table-space-text-post=€, table-align-text-post=true}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=-3.2]|
                    S[table-format=1.2]|
                    S[table-format=-3.2]
                    |S[table-format=-3.2]|}  

    \hline
    {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\ 
    \hline
    -199,37 € & 0,00 € & 33,27 € & 166,10 € \\
    252,56 € & 0,00 € & -409,58 € & 157,02 € \\
    104,67 € & 0,00 € & -40,18 € & -64,48 € \\
    0,17 € & 0,00 € & -2,52 € & 2,35 € \\
    0,00 € & 0,00 € & 0,00 € & 0,00 € \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

To avoid repeating the € symbol over and over again, I'd either put it into the column header of the corresponding columns or even into the caption of the table.

Answer (score 4):

Since so many have provided solution, I provide one using [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) to set a note in the caption regarding euro, and with columns of equal width (using [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `w`-column).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption,array}
\usepackage[flushleft, online]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}    

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Caption for table~\ref{tab:a}, which has both a tablenote\tnote{a} and a label \label{tab:a}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{w{r}{1.3cm}}@{}}  
\toprule    
%\multicolumn{1}{w{c}{1cm}}{\small A} & \multicolumn{1}{w{c}{1cm}}{\kern1.2em\small B} &
%\multicolumn{1}{w{c}{1cm}}{\kern1em\small C} & \multicolumn{1}{w{c}{1cm}@{}}{\kern1em\small D} \\ 
\small\scshape Head A & \small Head B &\small Head C &\small Head D \\
\midrule
$-$199,37   & 0,00  &   33,27       & 166,10  \\
    252,56  & 0,00  &   $-$409,58   & 157,02  \\
    104,67  & 0,00  & $-$40,18      & $-$64,48  \\
    0,17    & 0,00  & $-$2,52       & 2,35  \\
    0,00    & 0,00  & 0,00          & 0,00  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] \footnotesize All numbers are in Euro
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally same solution, but slightly improved with a thin unbreakble space between number and euro, and some padding at toˆof rows with `\extrarowheight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\sisetup{table-format =-3.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-post=€, table-align-text-post=false}
    \begin{tabular}{|S|S|S|S|}
    \hline
    {A} & {B} & {C} & {D} \\
    \hline
    -199,37\,€ & 0,00 \,€ & 33,27 \,€ & 166,10 \\
    252,56 \,€ & 0,00 \,€ & -409,58 \,€ & 157,02 \,€ \\
    104,67 \,€ & 0,00 \,€ & -40,18 \,€ & -64,48 \,€ \\
    0,17 \,€ & 0,00 \,€ & -2,52 \,€ & 2,35 \,€ \\
    0,00 \,€ & 0,00 \,€ & 0,00 \,€ & 0,00 \,€ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]